# What is a thread-safe way to maintain a global state accessible by all threads

Tags: c#, .net

I have a client/server setup with a proxy sitting between them. I'd like the proxy to behave a bit smarter so that when 5 clients are connected, certain packets can be relayed from client to client instead of client -> server -> client. Each client is currently getting their own thread so what is the best way to share a global state that has references to the other clients. This state object would really just hold an id associated to each client and a reference to their socket so i can send on it.

Would something as simple as a dictionary work? My concern is that while accessing the dictionary i might have another client connect or disconnect which would be modifying the dictionary as im accessing it.

Comment: This question cannot be answered generically. As it stands I don't think you receive useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary would work, *if dictionary is the data structure suitable for your situation*. This decision has little to do with multithreading.

That said, if you decide to use a dictionary, you should synchronize the access to it using

- e.g. the `lock` statements
- or switching to [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), a thread-safe version of `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).

But in the context of C#, you need to make sure you are carefully and appropriately using the `lock` keyword. This stuff is *hard*, and very easy to get wrong in catastrophic ways.

Answer (score 0):

If your proxy is set up as a WCF service then you could use the ASP.NET cache. Session state in WCF is per call, but the cache is still there lurking behind the scenes. Note that this is simply going to give you caching - it is not going to give you any pre-rolled access control to the cache, so you can still get race issues.

For further info on using the Cache, check this previous SO question How to return [HttpContext.Current.Cache from WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490913/how-to-return-httpcontext-current-cache-from-wcf) and this blog post [Enable Session State in a WCF service](http://tahirkhanstechnicalblog.blogspot.co.nz/2011/05/enable-session-state-in-wcf-service.html) .