# How to enable and share Cached Items in WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service, httpcontext

I have a WCF Service which is hosted in my Web Application. Both are hosted under the same virtual directory. Don't they run under the same Application Domain and share the HttpContext?

I added a new item to my cache from within the WCF service:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["FirstName"] = "Will";
```

How could I access this value from the web page?

I tried the below after calling the WCF web service but it was null:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["FirstName"]
```

Thanks,

Comment: this should be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/490927/754438

Comment: thanks. Actually, I used HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("FirstName", "Will", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(12), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration); and it worked fine :)

Comment: @TheLight You should post this as the answer and mark it as such.